# Range of a function question

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, rational-functions

So I have a question which goes like : The number of real values that the function $\frac {x^2-3x+2}{x^2+x-6} $ can't take is ?

**My attempt**: So let us assume the given function equal to $y $  then we have $(y-1)x^2+x (y+3)-2 (3y+1)=0$
Now since $x$ is real, the discriminant of the above quadratic is greater than or equal to $0$. Applying that condition gives $(5y-2)^2 \ge 0$ which is true for all $y $. So according to this method this function is able to assume all real values.

But this is not the actual answer. If we graph the function, we observe that there is a missing point discontinuity at $x=2$ and the function tends to reach $1$ as $x $ tends to $\infty $ but it never equals $1$.

So my question is: why does the analytical method not work? Is there any other method besides graphing the function which can be used to answer the given question?

I want to know because we can easily observe these points in this particular question,but we might not be able to do so in case of some other crazy function. So I want to know the correct method for this if it exists.

Comment: The phrasing of your question is unclear.  The real values that the function cannot take could be interpreted as the real numbers that do not lie in the domain.  Also, since you are interested in the range, you want to find the set of real values the function can assume rather than the number of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: for $x \ne 2$ we have $\frac {x^2-3x+2}{x^2+x-6}=\frac {x-1}{x+3}.$

Answer (score 0):

What you have done,  is found the **Range** of function...
As I understand from your question,  you said *Which real values of $x$ can be input*   , which means you need to find the domain...

You can factorise the quadratic equations in numerator and denominator. Then try to focus on the denominator and put up a condition of the function being defined...